# Instantiating and pushing view controller programmatically with custom initializer swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization, xib

I want to present a detail view controller in swift like so

```
let detailController = MyDetailUIViewController(nibName: "MyDetailUIViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), data:myData)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailController, animated:true)
```

The issue I am having is how to write my initializer for MyDetailViewController:

```
class MyDetailUIViewController: UIViewController {

private var data: MyData

init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!, data:MyData) {
    self.data = data
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

I am getting an error that my data property is not initialized at super.init call. Can anyone explain how I can accomplish this? I am sure I could make my data property optional and pass that in after initialization, but surely there is a way to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your `data` variable to be non-optional, you have to make sure that all `init` methods initialize it. This is not the case in your class, since

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

does not initalize your `data`.

Comment: So my take away from this then is that my data property HAS to be optional given the requirement to implement init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) ?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. If it's impossible to initialize it empty: `private var data: MyData = MyData()`

Answer (score 0):

If your declare your initialize as `convenience init()` then you will not have to declare an implementation for `init(coder:)` this may solve your problem as well.